# iOS : .Net API (asmx) Post Request With AFNetworking + AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, post, request, asmx, afnetworking

Hie all, I'm trying to send a post request on .net (asmx) API using `AFNetworking` class `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, here's my code that doing request,

```
-(void) request {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"test1": @"123",
                             @"test2": @"345"};
//    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/xml"];
    [manager POST:@"http://somewebsite.com/getdetail.asmx/AllDetails" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        NSLog(@"%@",operation.description);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);
    }];
}
```

I'm getting the following response string

> {"result":[],"status":"SUCCESS"}

And it prints the following error,

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x996a630 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

What's going wrong?

How do I send post request using AFNetworking, to .net asmx API, is that a correct way?